# Setting property for named parameters in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, jdbc, parameters, db2

I'm just getting into IBM DB2 and I have some fairly complex queries to create that will be based on user input in a Java webapp. The thing is, these queries will be put together with multiple different parameters in such a way that simply using a question mark is out of the question, so to speak. There would really be no way to know what is supposed to go where. Thankfully it seems that DB2 allows for named parameters, which makes things much simpler. I've pored through some of the DB2 documentation and it all seems pretty straightforward, but I keep getting an exception saying that the parameter marker was not present in the SQL string when it clearly is, ie, :parameter1 is in the SQL string, but it can't find "parameter1" in the setJccStringAtName method. I've set "enabledNamedParameterMarkers" to DB2BaseDataSource.YES in the Properties object being passed to the getConnection method, but it doesn't seem to make any difference whether I do or not, even though this definitely seems to be the way to do it. Maybe I'm missing something obvious. Does this also need to be enabled serverside?

Comment: A sample of your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are mixing pure Java development, and some concepts of SLQJ.

SQLJ allows you to write SQL queries natively in the Java code, between the tags

```
#sql{ ... };
```

However, there is a previous step to "prepare" the code and generate the .java file, and the .bnd.

When using SQLJ, you can use host variables directly inside your code, and it is not necessary to use the "Sets" methods.

```
String id = "A00";
#sql [ctx] iter = 
       {SELECT LASTNAME
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        WHERE EMPNO = :id};
```

There is a lot of examples in the InfoCenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.samptop.doc/doc/r0007622.html

There is IBM course focused in this technology: CG113, look for it on the Internet.